# Android Studio debugging extremely slow

Tags: debugging, android-studio

Gradle Build used to run 5-10 minutes each time, so I did all I could find on SO and other places: Instant run, Multidex, --offline,... and this brought it down to 10-20 seconds. Which is far from being excellent, but somehow acceptable. (Although compared to XCode this is quite shameful.)

But Debugging on the device with AS remains extremely slow. Clicking on anything makes AS react only after about 5-10 seconds each time. Global execution time is at least 10 times, if not more, slower than a Release run. 
I couldnt find much about how to speed up running in debug mode.

So, my question really is: has anyone succeeded in having acceptable execution times in debug mode in Android Studio and what needs to be done to achieve it?

Comment: completely agree . after build tools 24,i feel very unconfortable. I takes too long to start the debugger, unable to run apk in debug mode in devices ...

Comment: My first webservice call to the server is jamming mine up for over a minute. In normal run mode it only takes 200ms !

Comment: Any luck with this ?